# How to Debug Variables in Smarty like in PHP var_dump()

Tags: php, templates, debugging, smarty

I have some variables inside a template and I don't know where I assigned them. I need to know what is inside a particular variable; for instance, say I have a variable in smarty called `member`. I tried with `{debug}` but it didn't work, and no popup was shown.

How can I output/debug smarty variables using something like `var_dump()` inside the templates?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

You can use `{php}` tags

**Method 1 (won't work in Smarty 3.1 or later):**

```
{php}

$var =
$this->get_template_vars('var');
var_dump($var);

{/php}
```

**Method 2:**

```
{$var|@print_r}
```

**Method 3:**

```
{$var|@var_dump}
```

Comment: Resorting to php tags is not good practice and ideally they should be disabled for security reasons anyway. @debug_print_var (see answer from Chris) is a much better solition.

Comment: With the latest version of Smarty disabling the `{php}...{/php}` tags, Methods 2 or 3 are better options.

Comment: Output looks even better if you surround it with <pre> tags. Methods above are the best.

Comment: Add an additional param to print_r() to make it return the output to smarty, to avoid an extra echo at the end:
    {$var|@print_r:true}

Comment: Most clean view of the variable gives `{$var|@dump}` and it doesn't even need to be wrapped with `<pre></pre>`. `{$var|dump}` works just the same on Smarty 3.

Answer (score 126):

This should work:

```
{$var|@print_r}
```

or

```
{$var|@var_dump}
```

The @ is needed for arrays to make smarty run the modifier against the whole thing, otherwise it does it for each element.

Comment: A lot better then the chose answer.

Comment: better then the chosen answer? srsly? the chosen answer has those solutions in it too but just contains one more for older smarty versions, so I cannot really get how you could say it's better than the chosen one xD

Comment: @oliiix Just take a look at the revisions. In 2012 the answer was far away from where it is now!

Answer (score 30):

For what it's worth, you can do `{$varname|@debug_print_var}` to get a `var_dump()`-esque output for your variable.

Comment: Sometimes you are not sure what the variable is and many times `@print_r` and `@var_dump` did not work (in x-cart for example), but `@debug_print_var` output was there.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer is the only that works form me.

Answer (score 13):

just use {debug} in your .tpl and look at your sourcecode

Comment: Nice.  This actually created a pop-up window for me, so I didn't have to look at the source.  Had to disable my pop-up blocker though.

Answer (score 7):

In new Smarty it is:

```
<pre>
{var_dump($variable)}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Try out with the Smarty Session:**

```
{$smarty.session|@debug_print_var}
```

or

```
{$smarty.session|@print_r}
```

To beautify your output, use it between `<pre> </pre>` tags

Answer (score 3):

try this .... Set `$debugging`  to TRUE in Smarty.

Comment: sure i know that, but i need to do it without modding the core php files

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `<script>console.log({$varname|@json_encode})</script>` to log to the console.

Comment: Note: it's reqire to add a single quotes inside `console.log('code');`

Answer (score 1):

To debug in smarty in prestashop 1.6.x :

```
{ddd($variable)} -> debug and die

{ppp($variable)} -> debug only
```

An onther usefull debug tag :

```
{debug}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something prettier I would advise

```
{"<?php\n\$data =\n"|@cat:{$yourvariable|@var_export:true|@cat:";\n?>"}|@highlight_string:true}
```

just replace **yourvariable** by your variable

Answer (score 1):

in smarty V3 you can use this

`{var_dump($variable)}`

Answer (score 1):

`{$variable|@debug_print_var nofilter}` and you not need to add "`<pre>`" tags

`{$variable|var_dump}` show you more (but worse formatting) because `debug_print_var` not showing private variable in object!

Answer (score 1):

For better display :

```
{$var|@dump}
```

Answer (score 0):

In smarty there is built in modifier you could use that by using `|` (single pipeline operator). Like this `{$varname|@print_r}` will print value as `print_r($php_variable)`