# How can I display a smarty variable all information?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty template, in it there is a div, I add the `{$replies}` variable in it:

```
<div id="list-div">

    test div

    <table id="find_services"></table>

    {$replies}

</div>
```

but there shows `Array`, I can not see its inner struct:

[image: wn]

How can I see its inner struct? like `var_dump`'s function.

Comment: Try `{foreach}`? See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2431763/1415724). Which could probably be a duplicate of it.

Comment: already answered [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431763/how-to-debug-variables-in-smarty-like-in-php-var-dump)

Answer (score 1):

To get the array var_dump, just:

```
 {$replies|@var_dump}
```