# How to use debug or var_dump() in smarty php?

Tags: php, debugging, var-dump, smarty2

I am trying to debug in smarty php.

```
<div class="selected-plan submit-cell">
     <div class="name">{$lang.plan} <span class="red">&nbsp;*{$plans[0].Price|@var_dump}</span></div>
         <div class="field single-field">
              <select form="listing_form" name="plan">
                  <option value="0">{$lang.select}</option>
```

$plans:

[image]

But result:

[image]

what's the problem?
Reference: [how-to-debug-variables-in-smarty-like-in-php-var-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431763/how-to-debug-variables-in-smarty-like-in-php-var-dump)

Comment: I've not used smarty in a long time, but does the reference possibly need to be: `{$plans[0]['Price']|@var_dump}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow syntax for debugging in smarty php:

```
{debug_vars varX = $plans[0].Price}
```